# The output is truncated with LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I try to get the show log output, but it gives me partial output, expected output 65000 bytes. How do I fix this?

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $request = HTTP::Request->new('POST' => $url);
$request->content("command='term length 0, sh log'")
$request->protocol('HTTP/1.0');
my $respone = $ua->request($request);
warn Dumper($respone->content); #It only gives me the first page (I've included "term length 0" in my command).
```

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable Example**.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): we need URL.

Comment: If it's a router, doesn't `Net::Telnet` more appropriate?

Comment: @GillesQuénot, the url for this is just a standard internal url (.cgi).
"term length 0" is the cisco way to get the whole logs in 1 page (to avoid user to press the enter to get 'more'). Prefer method is LWP::UserAgent instead of Net::SSH. Thanks.

Comment: You should include the router model and maybe OS version. Also, share what you can of $url so that someone familiar with that router can advise on the url/command format.

Comment: I would guess this is an issue with the request or the response rather than LWP::UserAgent, what happens when you use cURL?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to 'talk' to routers with [`Net::Telnet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use utf8;                                                                                                                                
use encoding qw[ utf8 ];
use Net::Telnet;
use Data::Dumper;

my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new(
    Prompt  => '/>/',
    Errmode => sub { warn "telnet warn $@" if $@ },
    Timeout => 20
);

$telnet->open( "172.17.20.1" );
$telnet->waitfor('/RETURN/');
$telnet->print("");
$telnet->waitfor('/Password:/');
$telnet->print('xxx');
$telnet->waitfor('/\>/');
$telnet->cmd('enable');
$telnet->waitfor('/Password:/');
$telnet->print('xxx');
$telnet->waitfor('/#/');
$telnet->cmd('term length 0, sh log');
```